# Export a global symbol from a Delphi DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, export, symbols

I'm trying to create a Gecko 2.0-compatible DLL in Delphi.

Previously (pre-Gecko 2.0) the DLL needed to export a NSGetModule() function. This worked flawlessly.

Starting with Firefox 4, my DLL is getting loaded (I have verified this though a breakpoint in my initialization section), but my NSGetModule() function does not get called anymore. This is the designed behavior because starting with Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4), a binary component is not supposed to export a NSGetModule() function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#Binary_components

According to these docs, my DLL needs to export a NSModule data symbol which points to a struct. In Delphi terminology, I assume this is a global variable which points to a Delphi record.

In C++, this is how you export the (global) data symbol:

```
define NSMODULE_DEFN(_name) extern "C" NS_EXPORT mozilla::Module const *const NSModule
```

My question: how do I accomplish this in Delphi? How do I export a global variable?

I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Delphi exports global variables from DLLs in a similar way to how it exports functions:

```
library exp;
var
  global: Integer;
exports global;
end.
```

Delphi can import global variables from DLLs, but it's a bit of a hack: declare a DLL import procedure of the same name as the global to import, then get the address of the procedure and adjust it appropriately. DLL imported procedures, from Delphi's perspective, are stubs that do an indirect jump through the DLL import table. Exported variables are linked by the OS loader by putting the address of the exported global in the import table, almost exactly like how addresses of exported procedures are similarly patched in.

For example:

```
{$apptype console}

procedure global; external 'exp.dll';

function GetGlobalAddr: PInteger;
type
  PPPointer = ^PPointer;
var
  p: PByte;
begin
  p := @global;
  Assert(p^ = $FF); // $FF $25 => indirect jump m32
  Inc(p);
  Assert(p^ = $25);
  Inc(p);
  Result := PPPointer(p)^^
end;

begin
  Writeln(GetGlobalAddr^);
end.
```

Of course, the latter details are implementation and platform dependent etc. Probably a safer approach is to use `LoadLibrary` with `GetProcAddress`, which will return the address of the global variable when passed its name. Of course, that's also platform dependent.

**64-bit update:**

In 64-bit on Windows, the code is slightly different. The opcodes are the same, but the addressing mode for the same instruction sequence is different; instead of a 32-bit absolute offset, it's a 32-bit relative offset.

```
function GetGlobalAddr: PInteger;
type
  PPPointer = ^PPointer;
var
  p: PByte;
  ofs: Integer;
begin
  p := @global;
  Assert(p^ = $FF); // $FF $25 => indirect jump m32
  Inc(p);
  Assert(p^ = $25);
  Inc(p);
  // 32-bit offset follows
  ofs := PInteger(p)^;
  // offset is relative to next instruction
  Inc(p, SizeOf(ofs) + ofs);
  Result := PPPointer(p)^^
end;
```

Comment: is this safe? compatible with 64bit? future version of Delphi?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the docs, I don't think Delphi allows for the export of global variables directly as the help on the exports statement discusses only routines. Also there is a very definite

> Global variables declared in a shared
>   library cannot be imported by a Delphi
>   application.

and it is probably safe to assume that if Delphi can't import them, it also won't export them.

I suppose the way around this could be to export a function that returns a pointer to the global variable...

Something alone the lines of:

```
type
  RGlobalRecord = record
    ...
  end;
  PGlobalRecord = ^RGlobalRecord;

var
  _GlobalRecord: RGlobalRecord;

function GetGlobalRecord: PGlobalRecord;
begin
  Result := @_GlobalRecord;
end;

exports GetGlobalRecord name 'ExternalNameOfGlobalRecord';
```

So, if the NSGetModule function returns the same struct as you are now required to export as a global variable, you could try to export that function with a name as required for the global var to be exported:

```
exports NSGetModule name 'NSModule';
```

Comment: This function will put a mov instruction before the address, and Gecko 2 probably expects a STRUCT at the address, not code or a pointer... Perhaps if you define the function as register and with an asm block you could then use dd, dw, db to POKE the information directly. It's crude and looks awful but might work. I also do not see any other way.

Comment: @Ritsaert: Thanks, I'll readily admit not having any experience with cross language dll use. If you have an example, please add your own answer and get some rep.

Comment: I don;t think this will work. Most logically would be to take a compiler with a small runtime (e.g. ansi C) that CAN export variables, and import the pascal variable into C (static, no DLL), and then export it from the DLL. Then link both the pascal and C module into one DLL. Free Pascal has CVAR and can declare external vars, but I don't know if this works with DLLs.  Anyway, afaik exporting variables from DLLs is not officially supported by MS (though many DLLs do). Best would be to draw Gecko's attention to this and have them change it into a function.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks. If you have an example for your suggestion, please add your answer (I'm not proud :), well not too proud anyway). And if you do, please draw extra attention to the part of what MS does not support... I think it is really important information.

Comment: Marjan: How many export examples do you know in the standard headers, e.g. the Platform SDK?  If I had readily made code, I'd answered, not commented. Note that Ritsaert is right, and your answer can't work.

Comment: @Marco, hey, no worries, I wasn't griping about your comment, though I see now how you could have taken my words as such. I just wanted to encourage extra information for the OP as the second part of my answer was a stab in the semi-dark from the start...

Comment: The technique described here wouldn't work. What could work is an asm block with sufficient 'dd' or similar data entries to fill out the expected length of the structure, along with a VirtualProtect in the DLL main begin/end to make the code page containing the structure writeable. But it's not necessary since Delphi supports exporting variables directly (though I don't know when the feature was introduced).

Comment: @Barry: Thanks. The docs I read originally were D2009's. D2010 doesn't even have `exports` in the index. The D2010 docwiki on the exports statements also does not mention exporting variables... If it has been available earlier than Delphi XE, it has been pretty well hidden :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Delphi solution. And it works even in D5 :)

```
function MyComponentConstructor(aOuter: nsISupports; const IID: TGUID; out _result): nsresult; cdecl;
begin
  /* constructor */
end;


type
  TCIDEntry = record
    cid: ^TGUID;
    service: Boolean;
    getFactoryProc: Pointer;
    constructorProc: Pointer;
  end;

  TContractIDEntry = record
    constractid: PChar;
    cid: ^TGUID;
  end;

  TCategoryEntry = record
    category: PChar;
    entry: PChar;
    value: PChar;
  end;

  TModule = packed record
    mVersion: DWord;
    mCIDs: array of TCIDEntry;
    mContractIDs: array of TContractIDEntry;
    mCategoryEntries: array of TCategoryEntry;
    getFactoryProc: Pointer;
    loadProc: Pointer;
    unloadProc: Pointer;
  end;

  PModule = ^TModule;
  PPModule = ^PModule;

var
  mCIDs: array [0..1] of TCIDEntry =
  (
    ( cid: @Sample_cid; service: False; getFactoryProc: nil; constructorProc: @MyComponentConstructor ),
    ( cid: nil; service: False; getFactoryProc: nil; constructorProc: nil )
  );

  mContractIDs: array [0..1] of TContractIDEntry =
  (
    ( constractid: Sample_CONTRACTID; cid: @Sample_cid ),
    ( constractid: nil; cid: nil )
  );

  mCategoryEntries: array [0..2] of TCategoryEntry =
  (
    ( category: 'JavaScript-global-property'; entry: 'MyComponent'; value: Sample_CONTRACTID ),
    ( category: 'JavaScript-global-constructor'; entry: 'MyComponent'; value: Sample_CONTRACTID ),
    ( category: nil; entry: nil; value: nil )
  );

  NSModuleElem: TModule =
    (
       mVersion: 1;
       mCIDs: @mCIDs;
       mContractIDs: @mContractIDs;
       mCategoryEntries: @mCategoryEntries;
       getFactoryProc: nil;
       loadProc: nil;
       unloadProc: nil
    );

  NSModule: PModule = Addr(NSModuleElem);

exports
  NSModule name 'NSModule';
```

Now if you can send me GenericClassInfo implementation in delphi that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed this does not work in FF 5 and FF 6. Instead you can add initialization block to check for firefox version at runtime at adjust mVersion accordingly.
Mozilla is intentionally breaking binary components, so this is a workable workaround even between different versions.

You can use Application.ExeName and http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/files/get_the_version_of_a_file.html

FF 5 - mVersion := 2;

FF 6 - mVersion := 6;

FF 7 - mVersion := 7;

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current implementation (this works in FF 5 and FF 6 and probably all others going forward)

```
type
  TCIDEntry = record
    CID: PGUID;
    Service: BOOL;
    GetFactoryProc: Pointer;
    ConstructorProc: Pointer;
  end;

  TContract = record
    ContractID: PChar;
    CID: PGUID;
  end;

  TCategory = record
    Category: PChar;
    Entry: PChar;
    Value: PChar;
  end;

  TModule = record
    Version: UINT;
    CIDs: Pointer;
    Contracts: Pointer;
    Categories: Pointer;
    GetFactory: Pointer;
    Load: Pointer;
    Unload: Pointer;
  end;

  PModule = ^TModule;

var
  NSModule: PModule;

implementation

var
  mtModule: TModule;
  CIDs: array[0..1] of TCIDEntry;
  Contracts: array[0..1] of TContract;

function GetFileVersionResourceInfo(const FileName, VerValue: string): string;
var
  S: string;
  Value: Pointer;
  ValueSize: DWORD;
  VerInfoSize: DWORD;
  VersionInfo: Pointer;
  GetInfoSizeJunk: DWORD;
begin
  // retrieve the size of the version information resource
  VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName), GetInfoSizeJunk);
  if VerInfoSize > 0 then
  begin
    // retrieve memory to hold the version resource
    GetMem(VersionInfo, VerInfoSize);
    try
      // retrieve the version resource
      if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName), 0, VerInfoSize, VersionInfo) then
        if VerQueryValue(VersionInfo, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation', Value, ValueSize) then
        begin
          S := '\\StringFileInfo\\' +
          IntToHex(LoWord(LongInt(Value^)), 4) +
          IntToHex(HiWord(LongInt(Value^)), 4) + '\\';
          if VerQueryValue(VersionInfo, PChar(S + VerValue), Value, ValueSize) then Result := PChar(Value);
        end;
    finally
      FreeMem(VersionInfo, VerInfoSize);
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetVersion: Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  sProductVersion: string;
  sModuleFileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := 1; // Firefox 4
  FillChar(sModuleFileName, MAX_PATH, 0);
  if GetModuleFileName(0, sModuleFileName, SizeOf(sModuleFileName)) > 0 then
  begin
    sProductVersion := Trim(GetFileVersionResourceInfo(sModuleFileName, 'ProductVersion'));
    if (sProductVersion <> '') and (sProductVersion[1] in ['4'..'9']) then
    begin
      // Firefox 4 = version 1
      // Firefox 5 = version 2
      // Firefox 6 = version 6
      // etc.
      I := StrToInt(sProductVersion[1]);
      if I <= 5 then
        Result := I - 3
      else
        Result := I;
    end;
  end;
end;

function MyConstructor(aOuter: nsISupports; const aIID: TGUID; out aResult): nsresult; cdecl;
begin

end;

initialization
  mtModule.Version := GetVersion;

  CIDs[0].CID := @Sample_CID;
  CIDs[0].ConstructorProc := @MyConstructor;
  mtModule.CIDs := @CIDs;

  Contracts[0].ContractID := Sample_CONTRACTID;
  Contracts[0].CID := @Sample_CID;
  mtModule.Contracts := @Contracts;

  NSModule := @mtModule;

end.
```