# Force system with nVidia Optimus to use the real GPU for my application?

Tags: delphi, opengl, nvidia

I want my application to always run using the real gpu on nVidia Optimus laptops.

From "Enabling High Performance Graphics Rendering on Optimus Systems", (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf):

> Global Variable NvOptimusEnablement (new in Driver  Release 302)
>   Starting with the Release 302 drivers, application developers can
>   direct the Optimus  driver at runtime to use the High Performance
>   Graphics to render any application–even  those applications for which
>   there is no existing application profile. They can do this by 
>   exporting a global variable named NvOptimusEnablement. The Optimus
>   driver looks for  the existence and value of the export. Only the LSB
>   of the DWORD matters at this time. A  value of 0x00000001 indicates
>   that rendering should be performed using High  Performance Graphics. A
>   value of 0x00000000 indicates that this method should be  ignored. 
>   Example Usage:

```
extern "C" {   _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001; }
```

The problem is that I want to do this using Delphi. From what I've read Delphi does not support export of variables even though some hacks exists. I did try a few of them but couldn't make it work.

In the same nvidia document I read that forcing the proper GPU can be accomplished via linking statically to one of a handful listed dlls. But I don't want to link to dlls I'm not using. (Why the opengl.dll is not one of them is beyond me.) A simple exported variable seems much cleaner.

Comment: What about just creating an application profile?

Comment: This Q looks like a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641983/export-a-global-symbol-from-a-delphi-dll

Comment: When you export the global from a C++ program, is the name decorated. Use dumpbin or depends to find out. Then apply same decoration to your delphi export.

Comment: @WarrenP: An application profile is somethins that needs to be done manually after installation, I don't want that. Maybe it could be done as a part of an installation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The question you're referring to mine being a duplicate of was one of the sources for my failed attempts yesterday. I received an error E2276 "Identifier 'NvOptimusEnablement' cannot be exported" when compiling.

Comment: @DelphiDabber Well, let's see if we can fix that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Decorating is disabled by the "extern C" declaration.

Comment: @Paul No it is not. Stdcall functions will be decorated. Cdecl functions don't have decoration.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, decorating is separate from name mangling... Whoops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I've read Delphi does not support export of variables.

That statement is incorrect. Here's the simplest example that shows how to export a global variable from a Delphi DLL:

```
library GlobalVarExport;

uses
  Windows;

var
  NvOptimusEnablement: DWORD;

exports
  NvOptimusEnablement;

begin
  NvOptimusEnablement := 1;
end.
```

I think your problem is that you wrote it like this:

```
library GlobalVarExport;

uses
  Windows;

var
  NvOptimusEnablement: DWORD=1;

exports
  NvOptimusEnablement;

begin
end.
```

And that fails to compile with this error:

```
E2276 Identifier 'NvOptimusEnablement' cannot be exported
```

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't like the second version. It's probably a bug. But the workaround in the first version is just fine.

Comment: I've managed to place a var in the OpenGL wrapper unit and in the initilization section I asm MOV $1 into the variable. I read somewhere that otherwise it would be ignored by the compiler. Running PE Explorer there is an export with the correct name and the value 1. Unfortunately I don't have an optimus laptop in front of me so I can't test this until tomorrow. But the Delphi part of my problem seems to be solved.

Comment: You don't need to use asm at all. The compiler won't optimise out writes to global variables.

Comment: Yes, the export is correct with the asm replaced by
`NvOptimusEnablement := $1;`

Comment: It seems that the OP was incorrect in his assertion that Delphi can't export variables?

Comment: @WarrenP That's correct. It's really a dupe. But the twist is that an initialised variable cannot be exported for some reason unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Delphi expert, but AFAIK it is possible to link to static libraries implemented in C from Delphi. So I'd simply create a small stub library, just providing this export, which is statically linked into your Delphi program. This adds the very export you need.

Comment: No, it is not possible to link static libraries.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Technically this is something that should be applicable to the PE binary in a postprocessing step. The GNU binutils contain a program called "objcopy" that's kind of the swiss army knife when it comes to binary manipulation. You could use objcopy to copy a static library into an already existing PE .exe, creating the desired effect. Just an idea; I never tried it, YMMV, but I think it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Your answer is still quite clearly wrong. It is factually incorrect. It's also trivial to export a global. As shown by the link found in the comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How is it factually incorrect? It's perfectly possible to manipulate binaries on the lowest level, on par with an assembler.

Comment: It is factually incorrect because it is not tractable to force a static .lib into a Delphi module. Even if it was, it would be pointless to attempt to do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'd not push it into the Delphi Module, but into the final executable binary. All that the NVidia driver looks for is if the executable's PE does export this symbol with the magic value. If you prepare a static library that creates auch a symbol export and ibject it into the .exe PE the NVidia driver will see it.

Comment: The Delphi module **IS** the final executable binary. That's what a module is in Windows. Anyway, how exactly do you do this injecting process, and why is it easier than using `exports` in the Delphi source code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Of course using `exports` is the easy solution. But how I'd do it the other way? Using the GNU binutils I'd first use objcopy and objdump to split up the PE file into COFF files for the individual sections. Then I'd have my static library, or COFF file with the symbol to export prepared and re-assemble, err, re-link the whole thing into a PE, using the info obtained with objdump to put things into the right places. **Or**, I'd write myself a small tool, that allows me to modify a PE binary's symbol and constant data section, adding new symbols with predefined values.

Comment: That's just not practical.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Depends. Symbol injection is a common problem, but I admit the tools are not very polished. But all it takes is one person to wrap the steps up and make an easily tangible tool for symbol injection and it's much more practical than an export statement.

Comment: @datenwolf - doable, sure, but practical?