# Export global variable in .NET executable

Tags: c#, .net, exe

This SO question [Force system with nVidia Optimus to use the real GPU for my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372931/force-system-with-nvidia-optimus-to-use-the-real-gpu-for-my-application) explains how to indicate to NVIDIA drivers to use NVIDIA GPU instead of IGP in an application.

The trouble is, my application is a .NET app and I don't know if there's any way of exporting a global variable with a .NET executable.

How do I achieve the same effect as the SO question above in .NET? e.g. Is there a workaround where I could modify the EXE post build to add that global variable export?

Comment: Tried http://lucasmagder.com/blog/2014/05/exporting-data-symbols-in-c-for-nvidia-optimus/ ?

Comment: OpenTk uses a different approach, based on application profiles: http://www.opentk.com/node/3144

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a go at the first one but I don't have an Optimus system to test...